# Powershell foreach runs multiple times too often

Tags: powershell, foreach, iteration

So, this thing made me finally create an account here :)

The following powershell script looks for all csv-files in a folder (which contain x- and y-coordinates).

It iterates thru them using *foreach* to display all coordinates as a drawn **X** plus the name of the csv-file as text in the upper left corner - and works just fine (at first glance):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$gui= New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$gui.width = 800
$gui.height = 800
$gui.BackColor = “Black”

$formGraphics = $gui.createGraphics()

[int]$colorID = 0
[int]$textPOSITION = 5

$CSVfolder = "\PATH\TO\CSV\"

$allCSV = Get-ChildItem –Path $CSVfolder -Filter *.csv

$gui.add_paint({

foreach($file in $allCSV){

    $colorID++ #shitty way of cycling colors :)

    if($colorID -eq 1){
    $colorVALUE = "Lime"
    }elseif($colorID -eq 2){
    $colorVALUE = "Red"
    }elseif($colorID -eq 3){
    $colorVALUE = "Aqua"
    }elseif($colorID -eq 4){
    $colorVALUE = "Orange"
    }elseif($colorID -eq 5){
    $colorVALUE = "Gold"
    }elseif($colorID -eq 6){
    $colorVALUE = "Lavender"
    }elseif($colorID -eq 7){
    $colorVALUE = "HotPink"
    }

    $nameCSV = Split-Path -Path $file -leaf

    $CSVname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #create and display name of each csv
    $CSVname.Text = $nameCSV
    $CSVname.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5,$textPOSITION)
    $CSVname.AutoSize = $true
    $CSVname.ForeColor = $colorVALUE
    $CSVname.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")
    $gui.Controls.Add($CSVname)

    $textPOSITION = $textPOSITION + 25 #add 25 px to this variable which is the y-value for .Location

    $mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen black
    $mypen.width = 1
    $mypen.color = $colorVALUE

    $coordinates =  [string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path $CSVfolder/$file #write values from csv to array

        foreach ($i in $coordinates) {

        [int]$x = $i.Substring(0,3) #split into x and y (separated by a tabstop in the csv)
        [int]$y = $i.Substring(4,3)

        $formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, $x-3, $y-3, $x+3, $y+3) #X marks the spot
        $formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, $x+3, $y-3, $x-3, $y+3)
    
        }

    } #end of foreach($file in $allCSV){

}) #end of $gui.add_paint({

$gui.ShowDialog()
```

I noticed a sort of flickering when drawing the X's so i put in a small lazy output to the console

```
Write-Host $colorID
```

to see what's happening. The script runs thru all files, incrementing the variable $colorID, outputting

1
2
3
4
5

which is ok since it where 5 csv-files, but then it does the same thing six more times over, so the console reads like

1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5

and so on until there's 7 times this output. The number of "additional loops" thru the script is files + 2 for whatever reasons, so if there are e.g. 4 files in the folder, it runs 6 times.

I then added a little randomness to the drawn X's (to make the lines not end in x+3, y+3 but like randomly in lets say x+4, y+7) and i could see that the X's where all drawn multiple times as well.

When i completely remove all code belonging to the text output

```
$CSVname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #create and display name of each csv
$CSVname.Text = $nameCSV
...
```

the X's are drawn a single time (like intended) plus the console output tells me it only ran once thru all 5 csv-files.

Separating the code, so creating 2 separate foreach-loops, one doing the texts only, then the second one drawing the X's didn't work out, it behaves just the same.

My best guess is that either

```
$gui.Controls.Add($CSVname)
```

makes POSH redraw the whole dialog or that

```
$gui.add_paint({
```

is somehow in the wrong place, but playing around with these didn't help

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're attaching a delegate to the ```Paint``` event specifically, and not doing it another way? There are a whole load of arcane reasons why a form might get redrawn, not necessarily just "when the form gets displays for the first time", so your paint delegate is probably being called multiple times (as and when the Windows Form client area gets invalidated, or whatever) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 where it says "Occurs when the control is redrawn.".

Comment: Should be : $coordinates =  Get-Content -Path $file.FullName #write values from csv to array

Comment: @jdweng Oh yes, that's better

Comment: @mclayton No specific reason, that's the way i build it from documentation and googleing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the reason,

```
[System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")
```

is forcing the multiple redraws; guess the title is wrong then, since it's not multiple loops after all.

Simply dropped it from the code.